# A function to make multiple plots from a data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have a large dataset. I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that will take x and y inputs for each type and plot them. ...  I pretty new to python and functions are very confusing to me.

For example - I have data about dogs. I have multiple measurements of height and weight for each dog type... Is there a way to write a function that will plot all these measurements on separate scatter plots for each dog type? make something like this : [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqYZ.png)  without splitting the df for each type manually and plotting it (which is what I did here ).. I have 60 different types ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is first get a list of the unique types in the dataframe (assuming it's variable name is `df`). Now, for every type, we get a different part of the `df`, which I called `df_tmp` in the example:

```
for t in df["types"].unique():
    df_tmp = df[df["type"] == t]
```

Now you can call a plot function using the data in `df_tmp`, which, essentially, is just a subset of the entire `df`.

Performance wise this probably isn't the best solution, however to me it's very intuitive.